# Combining multiple elements based on their children element values with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

Alright XSLT is apparently beyond me and I need some help please. I haven't been able to put together the multiple stack overflow posts that exist about this into one coherent, working section of code.
I have an XML file that has multiple entries like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <events>
      <event>
        <EventType>Blah</EventType>
        <title>Blah Blah</title>
        <RelatedLocations>Blah</RelatedLocations>
        <Date>Friday, September 2, 2016</Date>
        <DateYear>2016</DateYear>
        <DateMonth>09</DateMonth>
        <DateDay>02</DateDay>
        <Body>Derp</Body>
        <Notes>Notes are not displayed to the public.</Notes>
      </event>
      <event>
        <EventType>Blah</EventType>
        <title>Blah Blah</title>
        <RelatedLocations>Blah</RelatedLocations>
        <Date>Friday, October 7, 2016</Date>
        <DateYear>2016</DateYear>
        <DateMonth>09</DateMonth>
        <DateDay>07</DateDay>
        <Body>Derp</Body>
        <Notes>Notes are not displayed to the public.</Notes>
      </event>
    </events>
```

And I would like to combine them together based on the titles being the same and the RelatedLocations being the same so that they read like this

```
<event>
        <EventType>Blah</EventType>
        <title>Blah Blah</title>
        <RelatedLocations>Blah</RelatedLocations>
        <Date>Friday, September 2, 2016, Friday, October 7, 2016</Date>
        <DateYear>2016</DateYear>
        <DateMonth>09</DateMonth>
        <DateDay>07</DateDay>
        <Body>Derp</Body>
        <Notes>Notes are not displayed to the public.</Notes>
      </event>
```

The problem is that there are other nodes in the sheet that are totally different and some that are almost the same but have a different location. So I'd like to do an if statement (I think?) that checks the whole document for  and  that are the same as the current node and then concatenate the dates together into one node and then leave any other nodes alone. This is the code I've come up with

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" />
        <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:key name="title" match="event/*" use="concat(../@id, '-', localname())"/>  

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
            <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
        <xsl:for-each select="event/title">
            <xsl:when test = "(@title = preceding::*/@title)">
                This worked!
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:template match="event">
            <xsl:copy>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="title" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="RelatedLocations" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Date" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="DateYear" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="DateMonth" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="DateDay" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="Body" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="AgeRanges" />
            </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
```

Which clearly doesn't work. So please help and thank you.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Apparently you want to group together events of the same ... well, what exactly? Your code suggests an `id` attribute, but your XML does not have any such thing. You have to clarify *what* you want to be done before you can ask *how* to do it.

Comment: In any case, for grouping in XSLT 1.0 see: http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html

Comment: Ah okay that's my bad I do apologize. I wanted to group together events that have the same title and the same related location. Will try to make that clearer in the question. Thanks for pointing that out. And will look at your link now too.

Comment: Well then define your key as `<xsl:key name="k" match="event" use="concat(title, '|', RelatedLocations)"/>`. The rest should be clear from the article.